# Client-side improvements for heavy server-side traffic

Tags: networking, automation, bots

As an end-user I've noticed that websites dealing with a high amount of botting tend to have extremely high latency during times when bots are active, e.g. releases of clothing, sneakers, ticket sales. What I don't understand is how anyone can have an advantage when pages won't even load due to high server-side load. Sure, in a world where a web page loads instantaneously a script will be able to navigate through it quicker than a human could. But in scenarios where a user makes a request to a website to try to get concert tickets at the moment they release, they wait for the page to load for 5 minutes, and they're met with a message that all tickets are sold out, how are bots winning here?

My only theories thus far are:
-Utilizing a network for botting in a physical location closer to the endpoint for decreased travel time and thus getting their requests into the queue faster
-Increasing probability that a request gets through via increasing number of requests that a bot sends. I.e. our sad end-user is out of luck because their request didn't make it into the queue early enough, but some portion of regular human end-users *do* get lucky with a request that makes it into the queue early enough. By sending a very high amount of requests, bots can increase the probability that this happens. Of course in instances where tens of thousands of requests are all racing to be the first to reach a resource this strategy wouldn't make much of a statistical difference unless the number of requests was very high (thousands from a single botting service)

This is obviously all just speculation, but I'm very curious how this works and if anyone has insight!